# Error upon form submission in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, http

It appears my information is not being placed into the POST array correctly. I'm new to php so I'm not too sure why. I don't know what other information y'all need on this, so I'll just place the code and the error message. Any help/advice you could offer would be greatly appreciated.

This is the form after being rendered.
[image]

This is the error I'm getting after submission.

[image: The error I get after I select submit]

Here's the code snippets. I haven't included all of the html. I may be that I need to ditch the php and write stuff in java. Opinions welcomed.

```
        <h2 class="tgminix-padding-large" style="margin:auto;max-width:1000px">Calculating Total Percent Impedance Upstream of the Motor</h2>
    <hr class="tgminix-border-grey" style="margin:auto;width:80%">
    <p><span class="error">* Required Field</span></p>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialcharachars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>
          High Side Busbar Impedance (Real): <input type="float" name="SubstationHighsideEqivImpedanceR">
          <span class="error"> <?php echo $subImpedanceError;?></span>
          <br><br>
           High Side Busbar Impedance (Imaginary): <input type="float" name="SubstationHighsideEqivImpedanceI">
          <span class="error"> <?php echo $subImpedanceError;?></span>
          <br><br>
           Low Side Busbar Impedance (Real): <input type="float" name="SubstationLowsideEquivImpedanceR">
          <span class="error"><?php echo $subImpedanceError;?></span>
          <br><br>
          Low Side Busbar Impedance (Imaginary): <input type="float" name="SubstationLowsideEquivImpedanceI">
          <span class="error"><?php echo $subImpedanceError;?></span>
          <br><br>
          Motor Starting Power Factor: <input type="float" name="MotorStartingPowerFactor_num">
          <span class="error"><?php echo $subImpedanceError;?></span>
          <br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  <?php
    /* Locked Rotor Constants Array 
    $MotorLockedRotorConstants = array(
            array("NEMA Code Letter","Mid-Value Constant")
            array("A",1.6)
            array("B",3.3)
            array("C",3.8)
            array("D",4.3)
            array("E",4.7)
            array("F",5.3)
            array("G",5.9)
             array("H",6.7)
            array("J",7.5)
            array("K",8.5)
            array("L",9.5)
            array("M",10.6)
            array("N",11.8)
            array("P",13.2)
            array("R",15.0)
            array("S",17.1)
            array("T",19.0)
            array("U",21.5)
            array("V",25));*/
        if ($_POST){
            $SubstationHighsideEqivImpedance_real = $_POST["SubstationHighsideEqivImpedanceR"];
            $SubstationHighsideEquivImpedance_imaginary = $_POST["SubstationHighsideEqivImpedanceI"];
            $SubstationLowsideEquivImpedance_real = $_POST["SubstationLowsideEquivImpedanceR"];
            $SubstationLowsideEquivImpedance_imaginary = $_POST["SubstationLowsideEquivImpedanceI"];

            $MotorStartingPowerFactor = $_POST["MotorStartingPowerFactor_num"];

            $SubstationPercentImpedance = "";
            $TEMP_X_perc = $TEMP_R_perc = "";
            $TEMP_X_perc = $SubstationLowsideEquivImpedance_imaginary + 0.333333 * $SubstationHighsideEquivImpedance_imaginary;
            $TEMP_R_perc = $SubstationLowsideEquivImpedance_real + 0.33333 * $SubstationHighsideEqivImpedance_real;
            $RAD_ANGLE_TEMP = $MotorStartingPowerFactor*(pi()/180);
            $DEG_ANGLE_TEMP_cos = (180/pi()) * cos($RAD_ANGLE_TEMP);
            $DEG_ANGLE_TEMP_sin = (180/pi()) * sin($RAD_ANGLE_TEMP);
            $SubstationHisideImpedancePercent = ($TEMP_R_perc * $DEG_ANGLE_TEMP_cos) + ($TEMP_X_perc * DEG_ANGLE_TEMP_sin);
        } else {
            echo "There's nothing in POST. srry"
        }
       ?>
    <p class="tgminix-padding-large" style="margin:auto;max-width:1000px">
        The Substation Impedance is: <?php echo $SubstationHisideImpedancePercent; ?>
        <br>
        The Substation Impedance is: <?php echo $TEMP_R_perc; ?> $ + \mathbf{i}$ <?php echo $TEMP_X_perc; ?>
    </p>
```

Let me know if this is too ambiguous.

Comment: `htmlspecialcharachars()` is not a function in PHP, it should be [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). Also you're missing a closing quote and bracket on your `form` tag - it should be: `<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">`

Answer (score 0):

```
    REPLACE
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialcharachars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>
    WITH
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialcharachars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```